# Как открыть Qt project из терминала Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Создал Qt игру. Когда открываю из Qt creator все нормально работает. Но когда открываю executable из терминала выходит окошко и сразу исчезает.
Как правильно скомпилировать Qt project чтобы смог открыть из терминала ?

Comment: скорее всего версия Qt, которая задана в настройках проекта не совпадает с версией, установленной в системе. Посмотрите в консоли через ldd <имя бинаря> какие библиотеки не может найти далее по обстоятельствам

Comment: спасибо исправил !